# Does it make sense to override the save method in a mixin?

Tags: django, model, mixins

Does it make sense to override the `save` method in a mixin?

In my project I have, for good reasons, to override the `save` method in several models.
At first, I have to create a custom model class which inherits from `models.Model`.
However, semantically, what I am doing is giving a role to a class (rather than defining an object in its own right), that's why I think it's better to write a mixin.
An other reason is because we may use multiple inheritance in near future.
On the over hand, this line in overridden save method :

```
super(MyMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

does not make sense as it can only be used with a django.db.models.Model class.

```
class MyMixin(object):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        super(MyMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

Which is the technically better choice (Mixin or custom model)?

Comment: You say that your class inherits from model.Model. I'd recommend editing that phrase for clarity. I almost guarantee that you mean that your model extends django.db.models.Model

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way the mro (method resolution order) works, both methods are perfectly valid. The abstract model case is quite simple: you have a single inheritance chain, and each call to super is called on the next class up in the chain. So if you have:

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class MyModel(MyBaseModel):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The call in `MyModel` will propogate to `MyBaseModel`, and the call in `MyBaseModel` will propogate to `models.Model`.

With multiple inheritance, the inheritance chain is slightly different. The first class upwards in the inheritance chain is the first base class defined. So if you have `class MyModel(MyMixin, models.Model)`, `MyMixin` will be the first class upwards. Next, when `super()` is called in `MyMixin` (with a `MyModel` instance), it will look for siblings of the `MyMixin` class. That means that the next method to be called is the `save` method on `models.Model`.

Considering this, it is perfectly fine to use a mixin to override the save methods. In both cases, the `MyModel` save method will be called first, then the mixin/abstract model's save method, and finally the `models.Model` save method.

**Note:**

This is a simplified explanation of the method resolution order that works in this specific case. The actual algorithm for determining the order is the C3 linearization algorithm. A complete explanation can be found [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).